# Java infinite method run

Tags: java

I make a class to make Arithmetic operations on rational numbers the problem is when I run the program it keeps running and never stops or show results after many tries I discovered that the problem is the **reduce** method it is just stuck and never completed . any ideas ?

```
private void normalize() {
    if ( (this.num > 0 && this.den < 0) || (this.num < 0 && this.den < 0)){
        this.num = -this.num;
        this.den = -this.den;
    }
}

private void reduce(int n , int d) {
    int  r , L = 0; 
    while ( (n!=0) && (d!=0) ) {
        if (this.den > this.num)    
            r = den % num ; 
        else 
            r = num % den ;
        while (r != 0 ){
            for ( int i= r ; i>0 ; i-- ){
                if (den % i == 0 && num % i == 0 )
                    L = i ; 
            }
            num = num / L ; 
            den = den / L ; 
        }
    }
}

public Rational (int num , int den) {
        this.num = num ; 
        this.den = den ;
        normalize();
        reduce (this.num , this.den) ; 
}
```

Comment: note : when I delete the line reduce(this.num , this.den) the program work properly so the problem in the method reduce (int n , int d )

Comment: `n` and `d` are not changing within the loop. you'll need to somehow make sure eventually both `n` and `d` are equal to `0`.

Comment: the while loop says (n!=0) && (d!=0) but n and d are never re-assigned in the loop

Comment: Apart from not changing within the loop: You never do anything with those 2 passed values anyway, so what is their point exacty?

Comment: n refers to numerator (num ) and d for the denumerator (den) 
and I enter the values not equal to 0 , can someone please reedit the code or clearing the problem ?

Comment: Additionally, `r` is never changing as well so there's another infinite loop.

Comment: I dont know how to solve the problem of infinite loop I am new to java 
could you please edit the code , the reduce method should simplify the fraction for example if its ( 2 / 4 ) it should make it ( 1 / 2 )

Comment: @AliZain: Java is [Pass-By-Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). So even if you pass `this.num` and `this.den` into the method it will not change the original values. But passing fields is pointless anyway and while i still have no idea what exactly you are trying to do you should probably just use the fields directly and get rid of the method parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the source of your confusion. You're passing num and den to reduce(int n, int d), but n and d get assigned the same *value* as num and den, not the same *reference*. As such, even though the values of num and den are changing in the while loop, those changes aren't reflected in the values of n and d.

Note also that you're doing division on integers and assigning the result to integers, which may be mathematically undesirable.

One other thing: Even after you fix the problem with n and d, you have an inner while loop that will never exit, because the value of r never changes. You need to update the value of r in the loop so that it eventually becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your loop is that you're never changing the value of r, which contains the terminal value

```
while (r != 0 )
    {
        for ( int i= r ; i>0 ; i-- )
        {
            if (den % i == 0 && num % i == 0 )
            L = i ; 
        }

        num = num / L ; 
        den = den / L ; 
    }
```

Somewhere within your while loop, you need to decrement r, or create a condition to help it reach 0.

Comment: ok I dint know how to break the loops and maintain my goal from the method so lets just forget about my code . I want to update the num and den ( numerator and denumerator ) so that if I entered ( num = 5 and den = 10 ) it will become ( num = 1 and den = 2 ) , I would really appreciate it if someone posted a method to do this ( code )

Comment: If you really can't figure it out, search for "common factors [java]"

Comment: If this answer allowed you to resolve your infinite loop bug, please accept it as the answer.